# after convert datatable to xml string ,how to change the nodes' name?

Tags: asp.net, xml, datatable

I want to convert datatable to xml string and store it in database ,here is the code

```
        DataSet s = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = s.Tables.Add();
        dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Name",typeof(string));


        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Mary" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "Andy" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "Peter" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, "Russ" });
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        dt.WriteXml(sw);
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ToString());


the output is like :

<NewDataSet>
 <Table1>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>Mary</Name>
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Name>Andy</Name>
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <Name>Peter</Name>
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
    <ID>4</ID>
    <Name>Russ</Name>
  </Table1>
</NewDataSet>
```

how can I identify each row ? can i change the node for each row? I mean  tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking how you can get a tag name other than `Table1` or `NewDataSet` for your rows, try setting the dataset and table's name:

```
ds.DataSetName = "People";
dt.TableName = "Person";
```

Comment: I mean if I know ID is 1 ,I want to find the name of this ID ,is that possible?